# Sending file to another server using Form POST

Tags: asp-classic

I need to be able to send a file to another website from server-side Classic ASP code. The other website has a form with a file upload control, and I need to simulate posting to this form.

I found some sample code which seemed perfect for the job [here](http://multicolorengine.tineye.com/docs/code/classic_asp_sample.html), and it uploads the file without error, but the received file is not valid and when I inspect it on the other server the beginning of the file before the binary data has part of the posted data in it that shouldn't be there, eg:

> ntent-Type: image/jpeg
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="archivebox.jpg"
>
> ÿØÿà...

The receiving website code works fine when I upload data via a form, so it definately looks like the problem is with the above code.

If this code is not going to work, can anyone else point me in the direction of another sample for submitting files in this way?

Comment: are you sure the filename is on a separate line?  If it is then thats incorrect, it should be on same line as `Content-Disposition`

Comment: Strangely, someone had editted this part of my question. I have fixed it now. Filename is on the same line as content disposition, and "Co" is missing from "Content type" at the beginning of the file. Thanks.

Comment: John, that someone was Anthony himself (you can see it in the [Revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11062079/revisions)) - next time you can just Rollback the edit rather then rewrite the post. Anyway please post the exact actual code you're using, maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code sample in the link in my question, I modified it to build the request manually and it worked. I also converted to a single function that takes a binary file and one parameter and POSTs the request.

```
Function PostDocument(intDocumentID, binFile, strFilename, strContentType)
Dim objHttp, strBoundary, strRequestStart, strRequestEnd, binPost
Dim objStream

strBoundary = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272"

Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

strRequestStart = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""id""" & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf &_
    intDocumentID & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf &_
    "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & strFilename & """" & vbCrlf &_
    "Content-Type: " & strContentType & vbCrlf &_
    vbCrlf

strRequestEnd = vbCrLf & "--" & strBoundary & "--"

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Type = adTypeBinary '1
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite '3
objStream.Open
objStream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestStart)
objStream.Write binFile
objStream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestEnd)
objStream.Position = 0

binPost = objStream.Read

Response.Write binPost

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

objHttp.Open "POST", "(url removed)", False, "(username removed)", "(password removed)"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=""" & strBoundary & """"
objHttp.Send binPost

PostDocument = objHttp.ResponseText

Set objHttp = Nothing
End Function

Function StringToBinary(toConvert)
Dim objStream, data

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objStream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"
objStream.Type = adTypeText '2
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite '3
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText toConvert

objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary '1
StringToBinary = objStream.Read

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```